# Java Guava Cache : How to clear all cache entries?

Tags: java, caching, timer, guava

I have Cache with all customer details loading daily from db. But before the loading the daily customer details I need to delete all the previous entries in the cache.

Currently I am doing :

```
public enum PeriodicUpdater {

    TIMER;
    private final AtomicBoolean isPublishing = new AtomicBoolean(false);
    private final long          period       = TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(1);

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("TestUtils") @Setter
    private TestUtils testUtils;

    public synchronized boolean initialize() {
        return initialize(period, period);
    }


    boolean initialize(long delay, long period) {
        if (isPublishing.get()) {
            return false;
        }
        TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {

            @Override public void run() {
                try {

                    String path = getFile();
                    if(TestUtils.getFileNameCache().getIfPresent(path) == null) {
                        TestUtils.setFileNameCache(testUtils.buildFileCache(path));
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    log.warn("Failed!", e);
                }
            }
        };
        Timer timer = new Timer("PeriodicUpdater", true); // daemon=true
        timer.schedule(task, delay, period);
        isPublishing.set(true);
        return true;
    }
}
```

I am using the Cache here :

```
    public class TestUtils {

        private static Cache<String, Map<String, List<String>>> fileCache = CacheBuilder
                .newBuilder()
                .expireAfterWrite(4, TimeUnit.DAYS)
                .build();


    public TestUtils() {

             String path = getFile();
             fileNameCache = buildFileCache(path);
            }

     public Cache<String, String> buildFileCache(String path) {

            Cache<String, String> fileList = CacheBuilder
                    .newBuilder()
                    .expireAfterWrite(4, TimeUnit.DAYS)
                    .build();

            fileList.put(path, new Date().toString());

            return fileList;
        }
 /* doing some stuff with the cache */

        }
```

Is this the correct of doing ? I don't see the cache getting cleared. Can some one correct me if I am wrong ?

Comment: `Cache` has a method `invalidateAll()` that clears all entries. I don't see you calling that.

Comment: Since you're using a google library, I'll drop this note on [horizontal alignment](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html#s4.6.3-horizontal-alignment) from google's Java style guide.

Comment: Using google library and adopting google coding style are irrelevant. (Though I found the horizontal alignment of OP a bit disturbing too :P )

Comment: the biggest problem, although off topic, is OP is using enum inappropriately

Comment: OP - Original Post

Answer (score 9):

[`Cache.invalidateAll()`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/cache/Cache.html#invalidateAll--) will clear all entries currently in the cache.

That said, if you intend to reload entries daily, why are you only expiring the cache's contents every four days (`.expireAfterWrite(4, TimeUnit.DAYS)`)? Simply changing the `4` to a `1` would reload contents once a day.

Also, as Adrian Shum mentioned you're misusing enums. `public enum PeriodicUpdater` should almost certainly be `public class PeriodicUpdater`.